# Is it possible to run more than one client instance on a machine?

Tags: client, bitcoind

Is it possible to run more than one Bitcoin client at the same time on the same machine? I tried to set different working ports, but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need both a different RPC port (`-rpcport`), a different P2P port (`-port`), and a different working directory (`-datadir`).  You will also need to use the daemon (bitcoind) for everything after the first instance, since only one GUI can be running at the same time.

Comment: Ok. I set all these parameters differently but again I am not able to run 2 bitcoin client together. Should I use the daemon bitcoind instead of bitcoin ? I am working on windows ...

Comment: Oh, yes. I believe only one GUI can be running at the same time as well.

Comment: Yes, using bitcoind after few tests it seem work!

Comment: I followed these steps and it worked. However, I can't get peers using a different P2P port, `getpeerinfo` is always empty. How can this be solved?

Comment: first you should run getpeerinfo using bitcoin-cli with datadir and addnode with the local ip and port