# How do I run two instances of bitcoind on the same linux machine with different conf files?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I want to run two instances of bitcoind on my machine.

I know my bitcoin.conf file is in ./bitcoin/bitcoin.conf, and I know (thanks to [this thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/is-it-possible-to-run-more-than-one-client-instance-on-a-machine)) that I need to change my .conf file to point to different data dirs and RPC ports, etc.

However there is only one .conf file.

How do I go about pointing my second bitcoind instance to a new bitcoin.conf file? I copied the directory with the compiled code to a new directory, I am making the assumption that compiled code can be copied into another directory and it will work without problems.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `-datadir` flag to a new absolute location. Each instance will follow the `bitcoind.conf` in their respective directory.

Comment: There is little to no documentation on this topic, so I guess I'll just ask here: I specify a datadir flag by typing `./bitcoind -datadir /dir/location/here/`, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: ./bitcoind -datadir=/dir/location/here/ don't forget the =

Answer (score 3):

Probably, better to add new user.

Simply create new user:

```
# adduser bitcoin1
# adduser bitcoin2
# su -l bitcoin1 -c 'bitcoind'
# su -l bitcoin2 -c 'bitcoind'
```

Answer (score 1):

How to run two instances with same wallet

```
sudo su -
./xcoind stop
cp -r .xcoin xcoin2

cat .xcoin/xcoin.conf
---
rpcport=3776
port=3777
---

vi ./xcoin2/xcoin.conf
---
rpcport=3876
port=3877
addnode=127.0.0.1:3777
---

./xcoind &
./xcoind -datadir=/root/xcoin2 &
```