# Running Multiple Full Nodes on one Host

Tags: bitcoind

simple question. I would like to run several full nodes for Bitcoin, Litecoin, Darkcoin and so on, but don't they run on the same port (8333)? Will this just work or do I need to give them several different ports?

Cheers

Comment: Note that each of these clients may require a significant amount of memory, so you may have to check whether your machine has enough.  See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/is-it-possible-to-run-more-than-one-client-instance-on-a-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You need to give them different ports. Refer to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin on how to listen on different ports.

Comment: Is it rpcport=8332 in the config file the same as -port=<port> in the command line parameter?

Comment: That's the port that other programs on your server/computer can use to interact with the node. You can also change that port otherwise it will conflict with the other currencies. For the actual Bitcoin network connections you need the `port=XXX` configuration.

Comment: Thank you! https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/ confirms I am running the node on the right port. Will add other currencies now.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the different coins already run on different ports so you should be able to run these without problems (other than resource issues if your machine can't handled it).  You may need to just check the default port assignments and vary them.

If you want to run multiple instances of bitcoin for example you need to change ports.

```
-port=<port>           Listen for connections on <port> (default: 8333 or testnet: 18333)
-rpcport=<port>        Listen for JSON-RPC connections on <port> (default: 8332 or testnet: 18332)
```

You will allso need the -noupnp flag to disable upnp so that you can manually nat external ports.